# Difficulty with Go Rand package

Tags: go

Is there any Go function which returns true pseudo random number in every run? What I actually mean is, consider following code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "rand"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(rand.Int31n(100))
}
```

Every time I execute this code, I get the same output. Is there a method that will return different, random results each time that it is called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The package [rand](http://golang.org/pkg/rand) can be used to generate pseudo random numbers, which are generated based on a specific initial value (called "seed").

A popular choice for this initial seed is for example the current time in nanoseconds - a value which will probably differ when you execute your program multiple times. You can initialize the random generator with the current time with something like this:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

(don't forget to import the [time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) package for that)

There is also another package called [crypto/rand](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) which can be used to generate better random values (this generator might also take the user's mouse movements, the current heat of the processor and a lot of other factors into account). However, the functions in this package are several times slower and, unless you don't write a pass-phrase generator (or other security related stuff), the normal rand package is probably fine.

Comment: Another useful property of plain rand is that you can reproduce your results by reusing a seed.

Comment: With go1 time.Nanoseconds() does not seem to exist. You can use rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

Answer (score 2):

You have to seed the RNG first.

I've never used Go, but it's probably `rand.Seed(x);`

Comment: You mean this, package main

import "fmt"
import "rand"

func main() {
        rand.Seed(100);
 fmt.Println(rand.Int31n(100))
}. It is also giving same output all the run.

Comment: That's because you are seeding it with the static number 100 :-) Try using something more unique, such as the current time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())` works on Ubuntu. I spent forever researching `rand.Seed(time.Nanoseconds())`. I finally found the Example: Google Search 2.1 on the golang tour.