# Go: Get a set of unique random numbers

Tags: go

How do I get a set of random numbers that are not repeated in the set?

Go:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    v := rand.Intn(100)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

This gives me, sometimes, two or three of the same numbers. I want all of them different. How do I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    p := rand.Perm(100)
    for _, r := range p[:10] {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
87
75
89
74
17
32
56
44
36
0
```

Playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/KfdCW3zO5K

Comment: Great. I thought my answer was false. Apparently not.

Comment: Becuase... you mention the same Seed function than I do? (also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8288765/6309)

Comment: @VonC: Note my use of the `rand.Perm` function. Inserting the `rand.Seed` function before `rand.Intn` function, as you suggested, won't work.