# Go rand.Intn same number/value

Tags: random, go

Can anyone please tell me why the Go example here:

https://tour.golang.org/basics/1

always returns the same value for rand.Intn(10)?

Comment: The note on the side says why it is that way: "Note: the environment in which these programs are executed is deterministic, so each time you run the example program rand.Intn will return the same number."

Comment: @BojanB I saw that but I thought seeding would fix it. icza (see accepted answer) pointed me in the right directions.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

2 reasons:

1. You have to initalize the global [`Source`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Source) used by [`rand.Intn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn) and other functions of the `rand` package using [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed). For example:

   ```
   rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
   ```

   See possible duplicate of [Difficulty with Go Rand package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288679/difficulty-with-go-rand-package).
   Quoting from package doc of [`rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/):

   > Top-level functions, such as Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source **that produces a deterministic sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the Seed function to initialize the default Source if different behavior is required for each run.**
2. The [Tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/1) runs examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/) which caches its output.
   See details at [Why does count++ (instead of count = count + 1) change the way the map is returned in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966514/why-does-count-instead-of-count-count-1-change-the-way-the-map-is-return/32966784#32966784).

Comment: I included "time" in the imports and put that line before the rand.Intn line but now it just returns 0 every time.

Comment: @appliedJames Please also see reason #2. If you still have problems, edit your question and post your code. Aim for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK thank you that all clears it up. In fact, this whole question should probably be deleted. :)

Comment: I Go PLayground ok...why on my local machine I have the same 1 for any run.

Comment: Is there a way to embed the seed in the function call instead of having it be a globally set shared value? Thanks.

Comment: @JulianHernandez Yes, you could embed it, but it's a really bad idea. Seeding only needs to be done once. Why slow down every function invocation for something unnecessary?

Answer (score 10):

For the functions in the rand package to work you have to set a 'Seed' value. This has to be a good random value as decided by the user because - as per https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Seed this is the value golang uses to set the system to a deterministic state first to then generate a number based on that value.

For the sample code to work, you can try

```
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    fmt.Println("My favorite number is ", rand.Intn(10))
}
```

time.Now().UnixNano can give an arbitrary(like) number as the value is in 'one thousand-millionth of a second'

Answer (score 1):

As explained you have to initalize the global [`Source`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Source) used by [`rand.Intn()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn) and other functions of the `rand` package.

Besides using [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) option, you also can create the source using the methods [`rand.NewSource()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#NewSource) and [`rand.New()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#New).

```
source := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
r := rand.New(source)
randomNumber := r.Intn(10)

fmt.Println("A random number: ", randomNumber)
```

Comment: I believe the `source` generated by `rand.NewSource` is not safe for concurrent use so you might need to take an extra look at that.